# I want to compare two NSDate upto millisecond. How to do that in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Currently I am using  dateA.compare(dateB) but it return wrong value if two date are same upto seconds.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 1):

In an `NSDate` the millisecond part is the fractional part of `NSDate(). timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`. You just need to make the difference between two values using the dates you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Had a little fun doing operator overloading for NSDates so here is all of the comparison operators you would need. The only thing you have to adjust is within what margin of time are dates equal in the variable`timeMargin`.

```
let timeMargin = 0.1

func ==(left: NSDate, right : NSDate) -> Bool {

    let leftTime = left.timeIntervalSinceNow
    let rightTime = right.timeIntervalSinceNow

    let diff = abs(leftTime - rightTime)

    return diff <= timeMargin
}

func >(left: NSDate, right : NSDate) -> Bool {

    let leftTime = left.timeIntervalSinceNow
    let rightTime = right.timeIntervalSinceNow

    let marginalTime = leftTime - rightTime

    return marginalTime > 0
}

func <(left: NSDate, right : NSDate) -> Bool {

    let leftTime = left.timeIntervalSinceNow
    let rightTime = right.timeIntervalSinceNow

    let marginalTime = leftTime - rightTime

    return marginalTime < 0
}

func >=(left: NSDate, right : NSDate) -> Bool {

    let leftTime = left.timeIntervalSinceNow
    let rightTime = right.timeIntervalSinceNow

    let marginalTime = leftTime - rightTime

    return marginalTime >= -timeMargin
}

func <=(left: NSDate, right : NSDate) -> Bool {

    let leftTime = left.timeIntervalSinceNow
    let rightTime = right.timeIntervalSinceNow

    let marginalTime = leftTime - rightTime

    return marginalTime <= timeMargin
}
```

Implementation

```
let date1 = NSDate()
let date2 = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(0.08)

date1 == date2 ? "Date1 is equal to Date2" : "Date is NOT equal to Date2"
//Prints("Date1 is equal to Date2")

date1 < date2 ? "Date1 is less than Date2" : "Date is NOT less than Date2"
//Prints("Date is less than Date2")

date1 > date2 ? "Date1 is more than Date2" : "Date is NOT more than Date2"
//Prints("Date1 is NOT more than Date2")

date1 <= date2 ? "Date1 is less than or equal to Date2" : "Date is NOT less than or equal to Date2"
//Prints("Date1 is less than or equal to Date2")

date1 >= date2 ? "Date1 is greater than or equal to Date2" : "Date is NOT more than or equal to Date2"
//Prints("Date1 is greater than or equal to Date2")
```

***Note:***

Using `dateByAddingTimeInterval` doesn't always return the EXACT increment to the time. i. e. `NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(0.10)` Could in reality add 0.10001234 and therefore it would return a undesired result if it is a hairline fraction smaller or bigger than your time margin. So be careful if using this before comparing dates.